# Javascript Pennies Rounding Mechanism to the nearest multiple of 5 cent

Tags: javascript, rounding

In the Rounding Mechanism exercise, the total amount of a bill which ends in 1, 2, 6 and 7 cent should be rounded down while the total bill which ends in 3, 4, 8 and 9 sen should be rounded up to the nearest multiple of 5 cent.
For example, $3.01 shall be rounded down to $3.00. Another example, $6.23 shall be rounded up to $6.25.

For more example, refer to the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v64UL.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1** multiply by 20

**2** round

**3** divide by 20 back

```js
function round(x){return Math.round(x*20)/20}

// tests
[2.3, 3.13, 5.52, 7.88, 9.34, 8.12].forEach(x => console.log(round(x)));
```

Comment: That doesn't round to the nearest `0.05` as requested.

Comment: Oh, for `0.05` is the same, just instead `2` is `20`